# How Can I Restrict Or Limit Download Only For Users Come From My Site?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I have a site with name example.com and a windows server 2012 with IIS & PHP installed on it , I'm using from this server as download server on subdomain dl.example.com .
How can i config that if only a user come from example.com can download files on my server ?
for example i have this link (http://dl.example.com/file/mp3/name.mp3) on my site , i want if a user click on this link from my site (example.com) can download this file .

I can config this by .htaccess :
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example.com/.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]`
but the problem is that users can't download with download manager software like internet download manager & other software, they can only download with browser and some browser don't send the referrers site to server or Firewall of server erase the referrer before send request to IIS & PHP server for processing.

some one said that i can use from nonce but i don't know how to use it , How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Note that the referrer is an information set by the client, and as such shouldn't be trusted for anything related to security.

Comment: Yes , i mentioned that in question, if any one know about nonce or another way , please answer the question